# Usage of perfect infinitive ("Res mihi nondum comperta est, itaque sufficiat leviter admonuisse alios de hac quarta causa")

Tags: infinitive

In Kepler's [*Strena, seu de Nive Sexangula*](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/kepler/strena.html) we read:

> Res mihi nondum comperta est, itaque sufficiat leviter **admonuisse** alios de hac quarta causa.

which I translate as: This thing is not yet ascertained by me, therefore it should suffice to lightly suggest the forth reason to others.

Not sure how to interpret the perfect  infinitive *admonuisse* (in contrast with my expected present infinitive) especially after the present subjunctive *sufficiat*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the preceding paragraph Kepler has just described the fourth reason, so this seems to be simply a normal perfect infinitive with anterior meaning: "let it suffice to have suggested it", i.e. "let the fact that I have just suggested it be sufficient".